# Is it safe to use guava's ratelimiter on my company's login page?

Tags: java, jsp, guava

I noticed Guava's RateLimiter has the @Beta annotation, so intelliJ gives a warning saying it is unstable.

I would like to use it like this in my companie's login page to ratelimit incoming requests.

```
RateLimiter throttle = new RateLimitter.create(1.0);


public void doLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResp0onse response){
    throttle.acquire(); //or throttle.tryAcquire();
    //do the rest of the login


}
```

Will this work as intended? Or should I stay away from incorprating this into such a big functionality of my company because of the @Beta tag?

Comment: *"Signifies that a public API (public class, method or field) is subject to incompatible changes, or even removal, in a future release. An API bearing this annotation is exempt from any compatibility guarantees made by its containing library. Note that the presence of this annotation implies nothing about the quality or performance of the API in question, only the fact that it is not "API-frozen." "* - is that a problem for you? Probably not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`@Beta`](https://guava.dev/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/Beta.html) annotation is documented as:

> Signifies that a public API (public class, method or field) is subject to incompatible changes, or even removal, in a future release. An API bearing this annotation is exempt from any compatibility guarantees made by its containing library. Note that the presence of this annotation implies nothing about the quality or performance of the API in question, only the fact that it is not "API-frozen."
>
> It is generally safe for applications to depend on beta APIs, at the cost of some extra work during upgrades. However it is generally inadvisable for libraries (which get included on users' CLASSPATHs, outside the library developers' control) to do so.

This means that if you upgrade to a newer version of Guava, you may need to port your changes over to match a new API definition. However, there's no implication about the quality, performance, or reliability of this API.

However, the use of this RateLimiter in a logic page isn't really that good of an idea. consider whether a rate limit of 1 QPS per server is suitable for your login page. Your users and employees may encounter unavailability if multiple logins are attempted at the same time, and if you use `acquire` instead of `tryAcquire` you will block your handler threads. You should consider *why* you are interested in rate-limiting global accesses to this function and adapt accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the response - I'm not sure if you are familiar with RateLimiter, but will what I have written in the description work for any java function? Are there any drawbacks to implementing a ratelimiter in this way?

Comment: @JackHerer It "works" for any Java function insofar as it does what it is documented to do. All you do is attempt to acquire permits from it. Whether or not it is a *good idea* to use in a request handler is a different question. Rate-limiting in this manner, as I mention, can lead to either a poor user experience or a complete failure of your webserver to respond to any requests while threads are blocked in the login handler.

Comment: Thanks - do you have any recommendations for a better way to rate limit requests? If this manner can lead to poor user experience, what do you prefer?

Comment: @JackHerer I don't have any good recommendation without knowing your framework. One strategy that I would consider right off the bat is rate-limiting on a per-user or per-ip basis. You avoid the risk legitimate users blocking each other with their traffic, while still gaining some security by limiting brute-force. In the end, it also does depend on why you want a rate limit, and if it's for security reasons, what your threat model is.

Comment: The way this login page is set up is it is a JSP page that calls a java function doLogin. It's old code otherwise we would have set it up a bit differently. I am trying to ratelimit on a per-ip basis, just not sure the best way to do this. Is it at the load balancer level? Or should I do it in java? And the reason is to prevent DoS attacks. Any direction on what the best way to implement something like this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If your loadbalancer has that functionality, it's likely to be designed against overload to begin with. If it has the necessary granularity, just use it. Beyond that, there are a few factors that need to be taken into account; a new question may be the way to go.